# Best way sending a long string from client Silverlight to server ASP.NET code behind in quick succession?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, json.net

I have a website that needs to act like a scanner - capture a normal image from a webcam and then process that image on the server. If that process fails to extract the required data (QR Code), capture another image and keep looping until processing is successful.

On the server side, I can process the string image using various classes - not a problem.

On the client side, I can capture an image using Silverlight.

Which approach is best in getting that string image from client to server for processing? I don't even need to send data back to client Silverlight as I could simply Transfer the webpage away when successful (but would be ideal if I could get a message back to the Silverlight App to stop so the user can remain on the same page).

Is using Silverlight the best way??? I've explored the WCF RIA Service option (which is completely new to me) but that appears only for linking to a database which is not necessary.

I'm not asking a solution here, just a pointer so I know which road to invest time in learning to meet this requirement. Never looked at JSON before... is that the solution?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use webservice  (.asmx) then you can pass the values from .aspx page to WebMethod in .asmx via JSON ..